# How to delete image from device after upload in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, image, file, delete-file

I have some images taken from camera that are saved in local device.
Then I upload them in a server so after I need them to be deleted.
I thing file.delete() is the proper code but that doesnt seems to work although i got no error at all.
I know i get the right path to my file because i use the same path to view the picture.
I also use imageCache.clear(); imageCache.clearLiveImages(); after delete .
I feel like the pics are saved in two different places in the device although i doesnt seem like it. Also i would like to add that although I only run it in physical device once the results are the same so i didnt bother doing it again so i only test it in android emulator if that has anything to do with it

Comment: `file.delete() is the proper code but that doesnt seems to work although i got no error at all. ` file.delete() returns true or false.

Comment: `I feel like the pics are saved in two different places in the device` Why? It is you who determines full path while taking a picture with the camera.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the best answer but there are actually two paths that need to be deleted. I do delete two different paths. One is app's folder and the other you can get await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); with this